# emberjs hasMany returns undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to implement a minimal emberJs app using fixtures and a one-to-many relation between two models:

```
App.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.Album = DS.Model.extend({
  Name: DS.attr("string"),
  Songs: DS.hasMany('App.Song')
});

App.Song = DS.Model.extend({
  Name: DS.attr("string"),
  Album: DS.belongsTo('App.Album')
});

App.Album.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    Name: 'foo'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    Name: 'bar'
  }
];

App.Song.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    Album_id: 1,
    Name: "asdf"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    Album_id: 2,
    Name: "Test"
  }
];
```

I can access the Album model through the console like this
    App.Album.find(1).get('Name') # => foo

Whenever I try access the Songs property trough the relation between album and song I get undefined:

```
App.Album.find(1).get('Songs').objectAt(0) # undefined
```

Any hints what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined which `Song`s an `Album` has. You need to specify `Songs: [1,2,3]` in your `Album` model.

*(Quite sure it's `Songs`, but it may `Song_ids`.)*

Comment: No worries. Is it `Songs`?

Comment: Is the name of the properties should not be lowercase?